# How to change the Legend Icon in SfCircularChart() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, icons, legend

I'm using RadialBarSeries() inside SfCircularChart().
After calling `Legend()` (in the property `legend` in `SfCircularChart()`),
I got the following:
[image]

I want to change these circular icons to normal square icons.
This is my code:

```
  child: SfCircularChart(
    legend: Legend(
      isVisible: true,
      overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap,
      position: LegendPosition.left,
    ),
    series: <CircularSeries>[
      RadialBarSeries<Qualification, String>(
        dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true),
        dataSource: _qualifications,
        xValueMapper: (Qualification data, _) => data.name,
        yValueMapper: (Qualification data, _) => data.value
      )
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
 child: SfCircularChart(
    title: ChartTitle(text: 'Advances'),
    palette: const <Color>[
      Color(0xFFffc107),
      Color(0xFF0386E8),
    ],
    legend: Legend(
      isVisible: true,
      overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap,
      position: LegendPosition.left,
    ),
    tooltipBehavior: _tooltipData,
    series: <CircularSeries>[
      RadialBarSeries<ChartData, String>(
          legendIconType: LegendIconType.seriesType,
          dataSource: _chartData,
          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.name,
          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.value,
          dataLabelSettings: const DataLabelSettings(
            isVisible: true,
          ),
          enableTooltip: true,
          cornerStyle: CornerStyle.endCurve,
          maximumValue: 100)
    ],
  ),
```

- legendIconType: specifies the shape of the legend.

  - legendIconType: LegendIconType.seriesType,
  - legendIconType: LegendIconType.circle,
  - see more [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/LegendIconType.html)

Documentation: [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/circular-charts/chart-types/radial-bar-chart)

Comment: Thanks it's working